# With ember-data is there a method for querying locally available objects?

Tags: ember.js

I have created a model that is populated locally on the client, upon initializing the application.

The `findQuery` method always does an ajax request, for example:

```
App.store.find(App.Person, {name: 'John'})
```

even in the case where an `App.Person` with `name:John` has already been loaded. The `find` method which takes an id, looks at the local storage first. But I need to be able to perform queries by attribute.

My question is whether there exists a method for **performing queries strictly on locally available data**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DS.Store#filter` method. A basic example is shown in the README on https://github.com/emberjs/data, section `Filtering Loaded Records`.

Comment: this answer looked highly promising but after a number of looks around I can't find the "filtering loaded records" reference you made. I realise a year in Ember time is an eternity so maybe its moved. In any event, would love to know if there is a new home for this information.